# Toggling a label class when a input is checked javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm going to do a quick code dump and I will explain as I extract it.

```
function findTotal() {
    var items = new Array();
    var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
    var total = 0;
    var id = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
        id = "c" + (i + 1);
        if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            total = total + parseInt(element.value);
            element.classList.toggle('active');
        }
    }
    console.log(total);
    document.getElementById('displayTotal').value = total;
}
```

So this code above is basically going a long line of checkboxes and checking which one's are checked and if they are it adds their values up then displaying their total at the bottom.

What I want to focus on today is this part

```
if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    total = total + parseInt(element.value);
    element.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

What I'm looking for it to do is go get the label of the input that is checked (testing for each one of them) and toggle the **active** class.

### HTML

```
<label class="hover topping" for="c4"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c4">BABYBEL</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c5"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c5">TOMATOES</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c6"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c6">OLIVES</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c7"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c7">MUSHROOMS</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c8"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c8">CHICKEN</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c9"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c9">MOZZARELLA</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c10"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c10">SALAMI</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c11"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c11">ONIONS</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c12"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c12">PEPPERONI</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c13"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c13">STUFFED CRUST</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c14"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c14">MEATBALLS</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c15"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c15">BACON</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c16"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c16">HAM</label>
<label class="hover topping" for="c17"><input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c17">SHRIMPS</label>
```

Due to Shalini request I've added the HTML parts that relates to the javascript don't worry about the other c ids at the start.

### UPDATE

I am now using the code that pkmiec provided below but now I'm getting a problem where the last input I check also gets toggled when I click a different checkbox. Its difficult to explain so I have [temporarily uploaded](http://fabulouschicken.co.uk/pizza%20website/) it (sorry if anyone finds this post another time and it's gone)

Comment: Can you plz share html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine - what's not working? If you want to toggle the label's class instead of the inputs, change `element.classList.toggle('active');` to `element.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');`.

Answer (score 2):

Meet [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and make it much shorter

```
function findTotal() {
    var checkedItems = document.querySelectorAll(".items:checked");
    var total = checkedItems.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {  
       //toggle class on input
       checkedItems[i].classList.toggle('active');

       //toggle class on label
       checkedItems[i].parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
    }
   console.log(total);
   document.getElementById('displayTotal').value = total;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it notified you but I've updated my question :)

Comment: Regarding your update --- I think that the quickest solution would be to remove 'active' class from all labels as first thing in findTotal.